# TFTP server do not receive ACK messages

Tags: tftp

I have installed a TFTP server on my Raspberry pi (tftp-hpa). The config file is as follow:

```
TFTPD_ARGS="--secure /srv/archlinux/"
```

When I connect from the rasp itself evrything is working fine:

```
$>tftp localhost
tftp> trace
Packet tracing on.
tftp> get syslinux/lpxelinux.0
sent RRQ <file=syslinux/lpxelinux.0, mode=netascii>
received DATA <block=1, 512 bytes>
sent ACK <block=1>
received DATA <block=2, 512 bytes>
sent ACK <block=2>
received DATA <block=3, 512 bytes>
sent ACK <block=3>
received DATA <block=4, 512 bytes>
sent ACK <block=4>
received DATA <block=5, 512 bytes>
sent ACK <block=5>
received DATA <block=6, 512 bytes>
sent ACK <block=6>
...
```

But when I try from my PC it's like the TFTP server never get the ACK messages and keep sending the first block:

```
$>tftp nexus
tftp> trace
Packet tracing on.
tftp> get syslinux/lpxelinux.0
sent RRQ <file=syslinux/lpxelinux.0, mode=netascii>
received DATA <block=1, 512 bytes>
sent ACK <block=1>
received DATA <block=1, 512 bytes>
sent ACK <block=1>
received DATA <block=1, 512 bytes>
sent ACK <block=1>
received DATA <block=1, 512 bytes>
sent ACK <block=1>
sent ACK <block=1>
received DATA <block=1, 512 bytes>
sent ACK <block=1>
sent ACK <block=1>
sent ACK <block=1>
sent ACK <block=1>
received DATA <block=1, 512 bytes>
sent ACK <block=1>
Transfer timed out.

tftp>
```

For information here is my iptables, as you can see there is no rule to filter traffic:

```
$>sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Can you help me with this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

friend! I'd rather answer late than never))
Your problem is most likely that you are constantly communicating with the server on port 69. But the standard states that after receiving a WRQ or RRQ request, the server creates a new socket on a different port (not 69) and responds from the new port, and waits for confirmation to the new port.